# How can I Sqoop a table from RDBMS to HDFS with no primary key?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

If there is no primary key and time stamp in the RDBMS table, then how will you import the modified data into HDFS using Sqoop?

Comment: Are you talking about incremental import?

Comment: add more details to your question. please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)